# state machine : exception during a behavior associated to a transition

Tags: uml

A behavior may be associated to a transition, this is the effect. I remembered to read that an effect and a guard should be without side effect and without excpetion.

But reading the version 2.5 of the norm, i did not find that again.

am I wrong ? If not, what happens if an exception occurs during an effect ?

A solution could be to defined a guard depending of the result of the effect, but is it possible ? I never do that in fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

p. 358:

> ♦ guard : Constraint [0..1]{subsets Namespace::ownedRule} (opposite A_guard_transition::transition)
>   A guard is a Constraint that provides a fine-grained control over the firing of the Transition. The guard is evaluated when an Event occurrence is dispatched by the StateMachine. If the guard is true at that time, the Transition may be enabled, otherwise, it is disabled. Guards should be pure expressions without side effects. Guard expressions with side effects are ill formed.

p. 375:

> Because a transformation or selection Behavior is used while offering tokens to the target node, it may be run many times on the same token before the token is accepted by the target node. This means the Behavior cannot have side effects. It shall not modify objects, but transformations may for example, navigate from one object to another, get an attribute value from an object, or replace a data value with another.

You should read the section `14.2.3.9.1 The run-to-completion paradigm` which explains in detail how transition happens. In (very) short, if an exception happens during a transition's behavior execution, this transition is not taken.

Comment: I am not sure to understand, p 375 is related to chapter 15 Activities and not State Marchines (chapter 14). And in fact my most important concern are related to effect exception in case state machine transition ...

Comment: You are right. This is the only passage (repeated elsewhere) that mentions side effects with behavior. There is nothing specific to state machine's behavior. However, activity and state machines both have the same parent (Petri nets) so this might be interpreted to apply to both. See also Behaviors/Summary first bullet points. YMMV. The specs are not flawless.

Comment: as i know, UML state machine is built on Harel's state machines which are finally built on petri net. So i am not able to say that state machines are like a petri net. Anyway i think that i mixed two points : side effects and exception during a transition. It is maybe not the same thing, for exemple, an effect on a transition could be to send a mail to an administrator and if smtp server is down an exception occurs, so what's happens to the transition ?

Comment: See my addition in the answer.

Comment: the referenced paragraph said : "During a Transition, a number of actions Behaviors may be executed. If such a Behavior includes a synchronous
invocation call on another object executing a StateMachine, then the Transition step is not completed until the invoked
object method completes its run-to-completion step." If an exception occurs, an exception which is not catch in the Behavior, maybe it means that the transition does not occur. But this is not said clearly ...

Comment: Well, what can I say? That's what the specs say. And they still have flaws.